# Flot Chart Columns multiple data series

Tags: jquery, flot

I am trying to leverage the jQuery Flot charting package to plot a data series and I want it to look something like this:

[image]

I've tried different Flot plugins like the [side bar plugin](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/flot/) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. The standard Flot library allows me to plot a bar chart like so:

[image]

```js
var dataEarnings = [
    {label: 'actual', data: [[1,300], [2,310], [3,440], [4,300]]},
    {label: 'estimate', data: [[1,200], [2,300], [3,400], [4,200]]},
];
var optionsEarnings = {
    series: {
        lines: {show: false, steps: false },
        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.9, align: 'center', horizontal: false },
        points: { show: true, radius: 3, symbol: 'circle' }
    },
    yaxis: { show: true, tickLength: 0 },
    xaxis: {ticks: [[1,'Q1'], [2,'Q2'], [3,'Q3'], [4,'Q4']]}
};

$.plot($("#chart-earnings"), dataEarnings, optionsEarnings);
```

Any suggestions or pointers to other Flot plugins are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do that without a plugin by using the normal Flot options, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teuzouao/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the Flot "bubbles" plugin I was looking for [here](http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/bubbles.html)...